# Comparing 2 large sets of IDs from different tables for delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails. I am trying to use the following lines to remove `database_a.shops` where not found in `database_b.properties`:

```
properties = Property.pluck(:id)
Shop.where("property_id NOT IN (?)", properties).destroy_all
```

Problem with this is that `database_a.shops` and `database_b.properties` each have over 500,000 records to compare, result in the following errors on second query:

```
from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:215:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:224:in `select'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:498:in `inspect'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried using `find_each`, but it still doesn't work and gives the same error. I guess the sets are too large to compare. How can I fix this?

Note that I can't use raw SQL because I want to use `destroy_all` in Rails to destroy the associates as well.

Comment: Have you tried without the array? Like this: `Shop.where("property_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM properties").destroy_all`

Comment: @MurifoX `properties` is in another database.

Comment: Oh, that's a problem! Neverming my comment then.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time operation maybe you could accept some slow performance and do something like:

```
Shop.all.each do |shop|
    shop.destroy unless Property.find(shop.property_id)
end
```

If it's not a one time operation I suggest that you redesign to avoid this problem. You can add data integrity to the Property class:

```
has_many shops, :dependent => :destroy
```